# Javascript inline condition: major than 0 return result if not return 0

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

It's possible to write in one line something like this?

```
let value1 = 10;
let value2 = 20;

let result = ( value1 - value2 ) / ( value1 - 1);
if (result<0)
 result = 0;
```

Something like this (but without having to rewrite the formula 2 times):

```
let result = ( ( ( value1 - value2 ) / ( value1 - 1) ) < 0 ) ? 0 : ( ( value1 - value2 ) / ( value1 - 1) );
```

Comment: `Math.max` exists ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) with zero as another parameter.

```js
let value1 = 10;
let value2 = 20;
let result = Math.max((value1 - value2) / (value1 - 1), 0);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yeah that's much cleaner than my anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

the logic with the ans with Math.max is good.

you also can try with following:

```js
var value1 = 10;
var value2 = 20;
var v;
var result = (( v = (( value1 - value2 )/(value1 - 1))) < 0 ) ? 0 : v;

console.log(v);
```